# Convergence of an Infinite Series involving Absolute Values

Tags: real-analysis

If $|a_n| < 10^{-n}$, prove that $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} a_n$ converges.

Could someone  give me a hint as to how to start this?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** If $|a_n|<10^{-n}$, then $\sum|a_n|<\sum 10^{-n} <\infty$

Comment: To be even more sure : $\sum_{n\geq 1} 10^{-n} = 10^{-1}/(1-10)=1/90$, as a geometric series.

Comment: To be sure even more, using the fact that, absolute convergence leads to convergence - we done.

Answer (score 0):

If $A_n = \sum^{n}_{i=1} a_i$,
if $n > m$,
$$A_n - A_m = \sum^{n}_{i=m+1} a_i < \sum^{n}_{i=m+1} 10^{-i} < 10^{-m}$$
(you can do better, but this is enough).
Then apply the Cauchy criterion.

Comment: Then $|A_{n} - A_{m}| < 10^{-m}$. Since $10^{-m} \to 0$, $|A_{n} - A_{m}| < \epsilon$ for $n > m \geq N$.